# I couldnt change dropdown menu font size

Tags: css

I tried to write font-size in css of nav li ul but it didnt change the font size. 
I only want dropdown submenus to have smaller text size than regular links how do i do that?

Here is Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N2Ert/1/

```
<li><a href="index3.html">Projelerimiz</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

.nav li ul {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        min-width:20px;
        margin-left:50px;
        margin-top:-35px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this css code:

```
.nav li:hover > ul li a{
font-size: 10px;
        }
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/N2Ert/3/)

Comment: It will be handy for you to give first level li a class name as active on hover using javascript/jquery.